# Is there any way in android to filter out the noise(Low Pass Filter) using FFMPEG library. Can someone help me

Tags: java, android, audio, ffmpeg, noise

I am doing an application which records audio, but the recorded audio has some noise (humming/static noise). Is there any way that we can remove the humming noise using the ffmpeg lib using a low pass filter. Is there any command for the same for ffmpeg

Comment: Check this https://github.com/tanersener/ffmpeg-kit

Answer (score 0):

I just found a library that solved my problem, if someone has the same problem this might help. The link to the library is given below:
https://github.com/lincollincol/AudioTool

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).